# The logic of the interaction between UISegmentedControl and GUI doesn't work in my app

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisegmentedcontrol

The functionality I tried to implement in the quiz game is looks like this:

Here is the `SettingsViewController` which contains the settings of an app, where user can choose the `difficulity` of the game and the `sequence` of the questions the game have using `UISegmentedControl`.

The `SettingsViewController` contains these methods using to implement this functionality:

```
@IBAction func didChooseDifficulty(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    difficulityDelegate?.didChooseDifficulity(
                            difficulity: selectedDifficulty)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(
                            sender.selectedSegmentIndex,
                            forKey: "chosenDifficulity")
}
    
private var selectedDifficulty: Difficulty {
    switch self.difficultyControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: return .easy
    case 1: return .hard
    case 2: return .insane
    default: return .hard
    }
}

@IBAction func didChooseSequence(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    sequenceDelegate?.didChooseSequence(
                            sequence: selectedSequence)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(
                            sender.selectedSegmentIndex,
                            forKey: "chosenSequence")
}
    
private var selectedSequence: Sequence {
    switch self.sequenceControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: return .sequentally
    case 1: return .shuffled
    default: return .sequentally
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupQuestionsSequence()
    setupDifficulty()
}

func setupQuestionsSequence() {
    if let sequence = UserDefaults.standard.value(
                                        forKey: "chosenSequence") {
        let selectedIndex = sequence as! Int
        sequenceControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex
    }
}
    
func setupDifficulty() {
    if let difficulity = UserDefaults.standard.value(
                                    forKey: "chosenDifficulity") {
        let selectedIndex = difficulity as! Int
        difficultyControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex
    }
}
```

I use the `DifficulityDelegate` and `ChooseQuestionsSequenceDelegate` protocols here:

```
protocol DifficulityDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didChooseDifficulity(
        difficulity: Difficulty)
}

protocol ChooseQuestionsSequenceDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didChooseSequence(
        sequence: Sequence)
}
```

Also here is the `GameDelegate` protocol, the main protocol of the game I use:

```
protocol GameDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didEndGame(
        difficulty: Difficulty,
        withScore score: Int,
        name: String,
        removeTwoUsed: Bool,
        callFriendUsed: Bool,
        audienceHelpUsed: Bool)
}
```

Here is the `GameSession` class using for the main logic of the game:

```
class GameSession {
    var questionNumber: Int = 0
    var callFriendUsed = false
    var audienceHelpUsed = false
    var removeTwoUsed = false
    var difficulty: Difficulty = .hard
    var sequence: Sequence = .sequentally
}
```

Here is the `Question` structure with the questions is there:

```
struct Question: Codable {
    let question: String
    let answers: [String]
    let rightAnswer: Int
    let difficulty: Difficulty
}
```

And here is the `GameViewController`, the main controller where is the game itself occurs.
I need to gain some understanding of why it's nothing happens when I change the `UISegmentedControl` states. There is no any changes of the game `difficulty` and the `sequence` of the questions occurs.

Here is the some code from the `GameViewController`:

```
weak var delegate: GameDelegate?
weak var sequenceDelegate: ChooseQuestionsSequenceDelegate?
weak var difficulityDelegate: DifficulityDelegate?
private var questions = [Question]()

var gameSession = GameSession()
var score = 0
var questionNumber = Observable<Int>(0)

var difficulty: Difficulty = .hard {
        didSet {
            gameSession.difficulty = difficulty
        }
    }
    
var sequence: Sequence = .sequentally {
    didSet {
        gameSession.sequence = sequence
    }
}
    
private var chooseDifficultyStrategy: DiffilultyStrategy {
    switch difficulty {
    case .easy: return EasyModeStrategy()
    case .hard: return HardModeStrategy()
    case .insane: return InsaneModeStrategy()
    }
}

private var setupSelectedSequence: SequenceStrategy {
    switch sequence {
    case .sequentally: return SequentiallyStrategy()
    case .shuffled: return ShuffledStrategy()
    }
}

func initialSetup() {
    delegate = Game.instance
    Game.instance.gameSession = gameSession
    questions = chooseDifficultyStrategy.setupGame(
        lifelineButtons: lifelineButtonsCollection)
    questions = setupSelectedSequence.setupGame()
}
```

It might be stupid, I'll be very glad if someone will help me understand what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the part where you give `sequenceDelegate` a value? Also, what are you expecting to happen when the segmented control is changed?

Comment: @matt What should I place as a value to `sequenceDelegate`? 
I expect the order of questions in the game will be changed when the state of the `didChooseSequence` is changed and the difficulty of these questions when the state of `didChooseDifficulty` been changed accordingly.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but if `sequenceDelegate` has no value, messages sent to it will do nothing. It's a house with no occupant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking in very broad terms, I'd say that the protocol-and-delegate mechanism isn't what's wanted here. The view controllers that interact with the user's preferences, GameViewController and SettingsViewController, don't necessarily exist at the same time, so they cannot communicate with one another.

What's more likely needed is some central repository, as it were, where the SettingsViewController can write down the user's desires and the GameViewController can read them. A common place to keep preferences like this is UserDefaults; it has the advantage that it persists over time, even between launches of the app, and that it is globally available (meaning any of your code anywhere can interact with it).